# PHP - Obtain data from an external script and use it in the current form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, plugins, simple-html-dom

I have created a script that will work as a plugin for Wordpress whose purpose is to get the data of the videos of a page (video title, video url, thumb url and total videos found).
My plugin works but the script is on the same page where the results are loaded so that it stays in Wordpress. But I want to externalize the script in charge of doing the search because I sincerely do not want them to be able to visualize my php source code.

So I tried to separate my script and just put the html and invoke the script using the "action" form.
But I do not know how to pass the loops of my external script to the local form nor how to pass the values of the variables. I tried to use the "return" and "Header Location" but it does not work.

Here is what I currently have:

Index.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['search'])){
$url = $_POST['keyword'];
$parse = "http://example1.com/?k=".$url;
$counter = 0;
$html = dlPage($parse); //dlPage is a function that uses "simple_html_dom"
   include("form_results_footer.php"); // I include the header of the page with the results (this part is outside the loop because I do not want it to be repeated).
foreach ($html->find('something') as $values) {
 //Here I run a series of searches on the page and get the following variables.
    $counter++;
    $title = //something value;
    $linkvideo = //something value;
    $thumburl = //something value;
    include("form_results.php"); //The results of the "foreach" insert them into a separate php in "fieldsets".
}
$totalvideos = $counter;
    include("form_results_footer.php");  //Close the form results
} else {
?>
<html>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <input id="keyword" name="keyword" type="text">
    <button id="search" name="search">Search</button>
  </form>
</html>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Ok, the code above works fine but I need to outsource the part where I get the variables of the part where I will receive them, something like this:

-> http://example.com/script.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['search'])){
$url = $_POST['keyword'];
$parse = "http://example.com/?k=".$url;
$counter = 0;
$html = dlPage($parse); //dlPage is a function that uses "simple_html_dom"
foreach ($html->find('something') as $values) {
 //Here I run a series of searches on the page and get the following variables.
    $counter++;
    $title = //something value;
    $linkvideo = //something value;
    $thumburl = //something value;
}
$totalvideos = $counter;
return $title;
return $linkvideo;
return $thumburl
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<html>
  <form action="http://example.com/script.php" method="post">
    <input id="keyword" name="keyword" type="text">
    <button id="search" name="search">Search</button>
  </form>
</html>
```

The loop results would have to be collected on the same page in the same way as in the initial example.
I hope you let me understand, thank you in advance.

Comment: Just for clear my confusion, this both are in your plugin directory. right? or in root folder?

Comment: In effect, they are in the directory of plugins. That yes the external file of which I speak will be in a different domain.

Comment: You can use cURL for this,

Comment: My script is already using cURL to get data from the "http://example1.com/?k=" page.
The problem is how to get the values of the variables generated by the script hosted at "http://example.com/script.php"

Answer (score 0):

Change form action url to self page in index.php and do cURL there which calls your another domain where logic is placed. that mean http://example.com/script.php

**index.php**

```
<html>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <input id="keyword" name="keyword" type="text">
    <button id="search" name="search">Search</button>
  </form>
</html>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    //your URL
    $url = "http://example.com/script.php?keyword=" . $_POST['keyword'];

//  Initiate curl
    $ch = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// Execute
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
// Closing
    curl_close($ch);

// Will dump a beauty json :3
    var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
}
?>
```

And in  http://example.com/script.php you just need to change `$_POST['keyword']` to `$_GET['keyword']` and few more change to return data.

**scrip.php** (from another domain)

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['keyword'])) {
    $url = $_GET['keyword'];
    $parse = "http://example.com/?k=" . $url;
    $counter = 0;
    $html = dlPage($parse); //dlPage is a function that uses "simple_html_dom"

    $return = array(); //initialize return array
    foreach ($html->find('something') as $values) {
        //Here I run a series of searches on the page and get the following variables.
        $return['video_data'][$counter]['title'] = //something value;
        $return['video_data'][$counter]['linkvideo'] = //something value;
        $return['video_data'][$counter]['thumburl'] = //something value;
        $counter++;
    }
    $return['total_video'] = $counter;

    echo json_encode($return); //return data
}
?>
```

I hope this is what you want.